# How to add deep links to an ReactJS Ionic Android Project

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, ionic-framework, npm

I've got a basic ReactJS Project and I followed [this guide](https://medium.com/how-to-react/convert-your-existing-react-js-app-to-android-or-ios-app-using-the-ionic-capacitor-a127deda75bd) to turn it into an android project with my output in the `build` directory.

I've successfully generated a working APK file. however now I wish to point `https://example.com/` URL opened by any browser on mobile to open my app once it's been installed. any help would be greatly apperiacted.

I'm not sure where to register this url to open my app, TIA

## Update

```xml
<intent-filter android:label="@string/title_activity_main">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:scheme="https"
        android:host="m.clipdrop.io"
        android:pathPrefix="/" />
</intent-filter>
<intent-filter android:label="@string/title_activity_main">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:scheme="http"
        android:host="m.clipdrop.io"
        android:pathPrefix="/" />
</intent-filter>
<!-- Accepts URIs that begin with "clipdrop://login” -->
<intent-filter android:label="@string/title_activity_main">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:scheme="clipdrop"
        android:host="login" />
</intent-filter>
```

The link clicked would look like this

`https://m.clipdrop.io/login?b=datahere`

then i have this code which handles the open url event

```js
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
import { App, URLOpenListenerEvent } from '@capacitor/app';

export default function AppUrlListener(){
    let history = useHistory();
    useEffect(() => {
      App.addListener('appUrlOpen', (event) => {
        var url = new URL(event.url);
        var benc = url.searchParams.get("b")?.replace("%3D", "=");
        if(benc){
          window.location.href = "/login?b=" + benc; 
        }
        // If no match, do nothing - let regular routing
        // logic take over
      });
    }, []);
  
    return null;
  };
```

## Update 2

File: `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="io.clipdrop.clipdrop">
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale|smallestScreenSize|screenLayout|uiMode"
            android:name="io.clipdrop.clipdrop.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBarLaunch"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <!-- Accepts URIs that begin with "http(s)://m.clipdrop.io -->
            <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="http" />
                <data android:scheme="https" />
                <data android:host="m.clipdrop.io" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths"></meta-data>
        </provider>
    </application>
    <!-- Permissions -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MICROPHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.microphone"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.AUDIO_CAPTURE" />
</manifest>
```

I have setup the [assetlinks.json](https://m.clipdrop.io/.well-known/assetlinks.json)

when clicking the link it opens in the browser instead, but there is this icon in the corner when it opens in the browser:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Capacitor, for adding deeplinks to your project, follow the native procedure. just like explained in [android docs](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking), you should have this in your manifest file (located in android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml):

```
<activity
    android:name="com.example.android.GizmosActivity"
    android:label="@string/title_gizmos" >
    <intent-filter android:label="@string/filter_view_http_gizmos">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

        <!-- **** -->
        <!-- This is where you put your deeplinks with the 'data' tag:  -->
        <!-- **** -->

        <!-- Accepts URIs that begin with "http://www.example.com/gizmos” -->
        <data android:scheme="http"
              android:host="www.example.com"
              android:pathPrefix="/gizmos" />
        <!-- note that the leading "/" is required for pathPrefix-->

        <!-- **** -->
        <!-- **** -->

    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter android:label="@string/filter_view_example_gizmos">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <!-- Accepts URIs that begin with "example://gizmos” -->
        <data android:scheme="example"
              android:host="gizmos" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

for handling deeplink requests and it's data inside of your app after it has been opened, use the `appUrlOpen` event as explained in [capacitor docs](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/guides/deep-links)

### **UPDATE**

**answer for your update:**

Since android 12, deeplinks in android would directly open browser unless you verify your applink. follow [this](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/verify-android-applinks) instructions for verifying app links.

Comment: please see my update, I have manage to add this to the apk and it works, with on exception, if i click the link i sent to myself via whatsapp, with the app installed, it doesnt open the app, it opens the web browser instead... any ideas?

Comment: tho, when the browser opens, on the top right side there is the app logo, and if i click that then it opens the app but it doesnt send any data with it.... all i want is the link to be clicked to open the app by the user, thanks

Comment: @DeanVanGreunen you have to verify your app (I've updated my answer accordingly)

Comment: I already have that setup tho [assetlinks.json](https://m.clipdrop.io/.well-known/assetlinks.json)

Comment: @DeanVanGreunen seems like you missed the autoVerify attribute, add android:autoVerify="true" to your intent-filter

Comment: I've done that, please see my update as its still not openning the application.

Comment: whats supposed to happen is like it does on zoom. it will open the app when you visit the website on mobile, and I would like to do the same, but its not working, I have setup everything as required.